# Enterprise Keywords Refiner

Tags: 2013, search, refiner, enterprise-keywords

I have in a custom content type for documents and the enterprise keywords column as a optional field. Now I want to have a refiner in my search for that.

The problem is, that the property mapped to it, is this:

[image]

So it pulls all the meta information and not only the enterprise keywords. The managed property "Keywords" is also not the correct one, there are a lot of entries missing. Also tried DocKeywords.

Which crawled or managed property is the correct one, if I would only like to have to enterprise keywords?

Comment: You might find the property here, there is a couple related to "Keywords". https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found the property.

I changed the values of the property called `owstaxIdTaxKeyword` for Refine and Sort which were set to `No` to `Yes - active` so I can use it as a refiner.

Of course only Refine has to be set to use it as a refiner.

[image]

In there I found the values.

Can anybody confirm, that that is the right one for enterprise keywords?